# LINQ group List<object> on baseclass attribute

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I got a List where I place instances of subclasses from a superclass.

Code for my classes:

```
public abstract class Vehicle : IComparable< Vehicle >, IComparable 
{
    public string Manufacture{get;set}
    public Int16 VehicleID{get;set}
    public DateTime ProductionDate{get;set}

    public Vehicle(Int16 _ Vehicle ID,DateTime _ProductionDate)
    {
        this.AccidentID = _ AccidentID;
        this.ProductionDate = _ProductionDate;
    }

    int IComparable.CompareTo(object other) 
    {
        return CompareTo((Vehicle)other);
    }
    public int CompareTo(Vehicle other)
    {
        return this.ProductionDate.CompareTo(other.ProductionDate);
    }

    public Vehicle()
    {}
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Car ()
    {
    }

    public Car (Int16 _VehicleID,DateTime _ProductionDate, Int16 _CarAttribute1, Int16 _CarAttribute2):base(_Vehicle ID,_ProductionDate)
    {
        this.AccidentID = _ AccidentID;
        this.ProductionDate = _ProductionDate;
        this.CarAttribute1 = _CarAttribute1
        this.CarAttribute2 = _CarAttribute2
    }

    public Int16 CarAttribute1{ get; set;}
    public Int16 CarAttribute2{ get; set;}
}

public class MotorCycle : Vehicle
{
    public MotorCycle ()
    {
    }

    public MotorCycle (Int16 _VehicleID,DateTime _ProductionDate, Int16 _MotorCycleAttribute1, Int16 _MotorCycleAttribute2):base(_Vehicle ID,_ProductionDate)
    {
        this.AccidentID = _ AccidentID;
        this.ProductionDate = _ProductionDate;
        this.MotorCycleAttribute1 = _MotorCycleAttribute1
        this.MotorCycleAttribute2 = _MotorCycleAttribute2
    }

    public Int16 MotorCycleAttribute1{ get; set;}
    public Int16 MotorCycleAttribute2{ get; set;}
}
```

I want to be able to group these instances based on an attribute in my base class, i.e Manufacture.

```
public class Grouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public K Key { get; private set; }

    public Grouping(K key, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Key = key;
        foreach (var item in items)
            this.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

- See more at: http://motzcod.es/post/94643411707/enhancing-xamarin-forms-listview-with-grouping-headers#sthash.kWyEfaqU.dpuf

something like

```
var sorted = item in allVehicles //including cars and motorcycles
    orderby item.Manufacture
    group item by item.Manufacture into vehicleGroup
    select new Grouping<string, object>(vehicleGroup.Key, vehicleGroup);
```

Any suggestions are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you interested for?

**1. Get all from one type**

Are you only interessted in getting e.g. Cars? Then add at the begin to your linq statement following condition:

```
.OfType<Car>()...
```

(Thanks to Stephen Kennedy, its more simple then "Where(one => one is Car).Cast()")

**2. Get types grouped**

Or do you want to get all types grouped? Then use

```
var list = allVehicles.GroupBy(t => t.GetType());
```

or

```
ILookup<Type, Vehicle> group = allVehicles.ToLookup(x => x.GetType());
```

Comment: That's not how I read the question but anyway: I'm pretty sure your code could be simplified to 'OfType<Car>()' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your input. .OfType<Vehicle>() solved my problems :)